# How to implement slider view with tabs in custom keyboard or input method service

Tags: java, android, emoji

I'm working on a android keyboard app. The only problem I couldn't get around is slider tabbed view like this:

[image]

I don't know how to implement tabs with view pager in an input method service. It's fairly easy to do with activities and fragments but no idea about how to get it done in a custom keyboard.
Can anyone point me in right direction?
Is there any available library for this or a nice hack?
I'd really appreciate your help at this point.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

For implementing sliding tabs with ViewPager you can refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) or in Android studio you can select from samples available while creating a new Activity.

If you want to add library support for it you can implement this [library](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji).

Mind the min sdk version of the library to avoid any trouble in future.

Comment: please read complete question before replying. I know how to implement it in fragments and activity. Read again thoroughly.

Comment: Did you had a look at the implementation of emoji library mentioned above?

Comment: I did.... I need to create an edit text to implement this....which is not possible in the case of Input method service. This works with in-app activities or fragments but not with custom standalone keyboard